# SignalR & Knockout parent - child callback issue

Tags: knockout.js, signalr, signalr-hub

I have the following javascript view models (need refactoring, but I'm looking to get everything functioning first), and the setup is a MessagesViewModel which holds a collection of **MessageViewModels** and the **MessageViewModel** holds a collection of **FeedbackViewModels**.  When posting a new message, it all works fine and the hub calls back and the UI is updated.  The issue is when I add feedback to the comment, the feedback persists to the database, but the callback isn't invoked - see the code:

```
public bool AddMessageFeedback(string txtFeedbackComments, string hdnMessageId, int userId)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            var message = new Message
                {
                    SDUID = userId,
                    MessageText = txtFeedbackComments,
                    MessageDate = DateTime.Now.Date,
                    MessageTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString()),
                    Poster = UserManager.GetItem(userId),
                    MessageDateAsString = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString(),
                    MessageTimeAsString = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString(),
                    MessageDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString()
                };

            MessageManager.AddMessageFeedback(message, Convert.ToInt64(hdnMessageId));

            Clients.All.messageFeedbackAdded(message);
            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Clients.Caller.raiseError("Unable to add feedback.");
        }

        return result;
    }
```

ViewModels

```
$(function () {

    $(function () {

        function messageFeedbackViewModel(feedbackText, poster, messageDay, messageDate, messageTime, owner) {
            this.poster = poster;
            this.feedbackText = feedbackText;
            this.datePosted = messageDay.substr(0, 3) + ', ' + messageDate.substr(0, 10) + ' ' + messageTime.substr(0, 5);

            var self = this;
        }

        function messageViewModel(MessageID, messageText, SDUID, SportID, poster, sport, feedback, messageDate, messageDay, messageTime, owner) {
            this.hub = $.connection.messagesHub;

            //message variables, initialised from params
            this.MessageID = MessageID;
            this.SDUID = SDUID;
            this.SportID = SportID;
            this.poster = poster;
            this.messageText = messageText;
            this.sport = sport;

            this.datePosted = messageDay.substr(0, 3) + ', ' + messageDate.substr(0, 10) + ' ' + messageTime.substr(0, 5);

            //message feedback collection
            this.messageFeedback = ko.observableArray([]);

            //html variables
            this.newMessageFeedback = ko.observable();

            //reference to message feedback collection
            var messageFeedback = this.messageFeedback;

            var self = this;
            var notify = true;

            //callback from server side hub
            this.hub.client.messageFeedbackAdded = function (newMessageFeedback) {
                self.messageFeedback.push(new messageFeedbackViewModel(newMessageFeedback.MessageFeedbackText, newMessageFeedback.Poster, newMessageFeedback.MessageFeedbackDay, newMessageFeedback.MessageFeedbackDateAsString, newMessageFeedback.MessageFeedbackTimeAsString, self));
            };

            //build message feedback VM's
            if (feedback){
                if (feedback.length > 0) {
                    var mappedFeedbackMessages = $.map(feedback, function (feed) {
                        return new messageFeedbackViewModel(feed.MessageFeedbackText, feed.Poster, feed.MessageFeedbackDay, feed.MessageFeedbackDateAsString, feed.MessageFeedbackTimeAsString, self);
                    });
                    messageFeedback(mappedFeedbackMessages);
                }
            }

            //client side post
            this.createMessageFeedback = function () {
                var innerMessageFeedback = this.newMessageFeedback();
                var userId = $('#userID').val();
                var messageId = this.MessageID;
                this.hub.server.addMessageFeedback(innerMessageFeedback, messageId, userId).done(function () {
                    console.log('message saved!');
                }).fail(function (error) {
                    console.warn(error);
                });
                this.newMessageFeedback('');
            };
        }

        function messagesViewModel() {
            this.hub = $.connection.messagesHub;

            //messages collection
            this.messages = ko.observableArray([]);

            //html variables
            this.newMessageMessageID = ko.observable();
            this.newMessageSDUID = ko.observable();
            this.newMessageSportID = ko.observable();
            this.newMessagePoster = ko.observable();
            this.newMessageMessageText = ko.observable();

            //reference to messages collection
            var messages = this.messages;

            var self = this;
            var notify = true;
            var userId = $('#userID').val();

            //load messages, calling server side hub method
            this.init = function () {
                this.hub.server.getAll(userId);
            };

            //callback from server side hub sending messages to client
            this.hub.client.allMessagesRetrieved = function (allMessages) {
                var mappedMessages = $.map(allMessages, function (message) {
                    return new messageViewModel(message.MessageID, message.MessageText, message.SDUID, message.SportID, message.Poster, message.Sport, message.Feedback, message.MessageDateAsString, message.MessageDay, message.MessageTimeAsString, self);
                });

                messages(mappedMessages);
            };

            //callback from server side hub sending error messages to client
            this.hub.client.raiseError = function (error) {
                $("#error").text(error);
            };

            //call back from server side hub sending new message and pushing to collection
            this.hub.client.messageCreated = function (newMessage) {
                messages.splice(0, 0, new messageViewModel(newMessage.MessageID, newMessage.MessageText, newMessage.SDUID, newMessage.SportID, newMessage.Poster, newMessage.Sport, newMessage.Feedback, newMessage.MessageDateAsString, newMessage.MessageDay, newMessage.MessageTimeAsString, self));
            };

            //client side method from form post
            this.createMessage = function () {
                var selectedSport = $('#ddlSport option:selected').text();

                var message = { messageText: this.newMessageMessageText(), SDUID: userId, SportID: this.newMessageSportID(), Sport: selectedSport };

                this.hub.server.add(message).done(function () {
                    console.log('message saved!');
                }).fail(function (error) {
                    console.warn(error);
                });

                this.newMessageMessageText('');
                this.newMessageSDUID('');
                this.newMessageSportID('');
                this.newMessagePoster('');
            };
        }

        //set up the viewmodel
        var viewModel = new messagesViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        //call to initialise
        $.connection.hub.start(function () {
            viewModel.init();
        });
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding your `hub.client.messageFeedbackAdded` callback after you have already started your hub connection.

The `hub.client.messageFeedbackAdded` callback is being added when you create a new `messageViewModel` which happens when `allMessagesRetrieved` or `messageCreated` fires. Both of these events happen after your hub connection starts.

If you *really* want to add a client hub method after you start your connection you could use [`hubProxy.on( eventName, handler(args...))`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs-%28No-Proxy%29#hubproxyon-eventname-handlerargs-).

```
$.connection.messagesHub.on("messageFeedbackAdded", function (newMessageFeedback) { /*...*/ });
```

However this isn't what you should do. You should define `hub.client.messageFeedbackAdded` just once before calling `$.connection.hub.start` along with `allMessagesRetreived`, `raiseError` and `messageCreated`.

You will need to pass the parent message ID (which presumably `hdnMessageId` on the server) to `messageFeedbackAdded` so the client knows which message to add the feedback to, but the message ID is necessary regardless.

If you use `hubProxy.on` inside of `messageViewModel` to add a new handler for `messageFeedbackAdded` for every message, your handler would be invoked for each subsequent invocation of `Clients.All.messageFeedbackAdded(message);` no matter which message the feedback was actually left for. This means that your client would show each piece of newly added feedback every message which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this makes sense as I was able to hit the function if I moved it into the MessagesViewModel.  I will take a look at this again tonight, and report back.

Comment: I think I managed to get this working, I will paste the code below tomorrow :)